# When trying to make desktop icons, some transparencies show up black

Tags: unity, icons, .desktop

[image: Desktop Transparencies inconsistently working]

Upgrade:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Exec=*redacted*
Name=Upgrade
Comment=Desktop Icon
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;
Icon=/home/.launchpad/images/Upgrade.png
```

LIFTOFF:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Exec=*redacted*
Name=LIFTOFF
Comment=Desktop Icon
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;
Icon=/home/.launchpad/images/DeathBall.png
```

Comment: Run:    `convert /home/.launchpad/images/Upgrade.png info:` then `convert /home/.launchpad/images/DeathBall.png info:` and compare.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something wrong with png format of **Upgrade.png**. Run:

```
convert /home/.launchpad/images/Upgrade.png info: 
convert /home/.launchpad/images/DeathBall.png info:
```

and compare.

In any case you can re-save **Upgrade.png** as PNG8 to make sure that it is exact inside the file. Change dir where your images saved (in your case `/home/.launchpad/images/`) :

```
cd /home/.launchpad/images/
```

Then run command which convert image to **PNG8 8-bit sRGB** (for `Upgrade.png`):

```
convert Upgrade.png png8:Upgrade.png
```